# currently using batch command, is it possible to point to a table of values?

Tags: batch-file

i am using batch commands to generate a list of text in a mylist.txt file. eg.

```
\\abc\asd
\\def\as
\\ghi\as
```

i currently have a list of data (about 2500 rows), a few values/columns each row that contains static information (similar to a database). the list is currently in csv format.

for example:

```
\\abc\asd   123   home
\\def\as   456   office
\\ghi\as   789   elsewhere
```

i need to match the values in the mylist.txt and use it to execute a batch command. may i know how can i go about doing this?

i was thinking of using function, meaning each function will be named as one of the variable's values.

eg. one of the functions will be called "\abc\asd". and when the mylist.text has the value "\abc\asd", the function will be called.

will it be feasible given that it will probable end up with 2500 functions? i am wondering if this is the best way to do it.. please advise, thank you!

---

additional info (edited on 12 Oct)

hi, i am trying to compare lines in a text file and if the line matches one of my predefined text, i want to execute a batch/cscript command. is this possible?

what i have currently:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
set /a c+=1
set myVariable=%%a

REM if this line contains my predefined string A, execute a cscript command A
if not x%myVariable:prefinedtext1%==x%myVariable% echo theCommandIWantToExecute


REM if this line contains my predefined string B, execute a cscript command B
if not x%myVariable:prefinedtext2%==x%myVariable% echo theSecondCommandIWantToExecute
```

Comment: When you state CSV, I assume Comma Separated Values. Are you sure that your file separates values with whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be done, and quite easily for a few functions. But it will be a pain to maintain, and performance may suffer with ~2500 functions.

Here is a trivial demonstration with your sample data.

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%C in (mylist.txt) do call :%%C
echo Done
exit /b

:\\abc\asd   123   home
echo Function 1 (%0)  arg1=%1 arg2=%2
exit /b

:\\def\as   456   office
echo Function 2 (%0)  arg1=%1 arg2=%2
exit /b

:\\ghi\as   789   elsewhere
echo Function 3 (%0)  arg1=%1 arg2=%2
exit /b
```

--OUTPUT---

```
Function 1 (:\\abc\asd)  arg1=123 arg2=home
Function 2 (:\\def\as)  arg1=456 arg2=office
Function 3 (:\\ghi\as)  arg1=789 arg2=elsewhere
Done
```

If the first value of each row represents a path to a batch script, then you can remove the `:` from the CALL, and then each batch script will be called. Your main script would then be tiny, and would perform better. But that is a lot of batch scripts to keep track of.

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%C in (mylist.txt) do call %%C
echo Done
exit /b
```

Comment: hi, my apologies for the delay in response. i am trying to execute a batch command for each of the functions. is this possible?

Comment: i am trying to compare lines in a text file and if the line matches one of my predefined text, i want to execute a batch/cscript command. is this possible?

what i have currently:


for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
set /a c+=1
set myVariable=%%a

REM if this line contains my predefined string A, execute a cscript command A
if not x%myVariable:prefinedtext1%==x%myVariable% echo theCommandIWantToExecute


REM if this line contains my predefined string B, execute a cscript command B
if not x%myVariable:prefinedtext2%==x%myVariable% echo theSecondCommandIWantToExecute